# Expression for finitely many events occur?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a sequence of events [B<sub>1</sub> , B<sub>2</sub>,....], We can express event that **infinitely many events** occur as

$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)$

How can I express the event that **finitely many events** occur in a similar notation? I am looking not looking for 
$S-\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)\right)$

Comment: $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)$$
is an event, not a probability.

Comment: @quasi edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: The expression
$$1 - \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)$$
is not meaningful.

Comment: @quasi can you please explain me why?

Comment: An event is not a probability, so there's no meaning for $1$ minus an event. You can have
$$1 - P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)\right)$$
which is a _probability_, or you can have the _event_
$$X-\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{n\geq k} B_k\right)\right)$$
where $X$ is the sample space (and where the minus symbol denotes set subtraction).

Comment: @quasi ok. Changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\omega\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}B_k\iff\{n\mid \omega\in B_n\}\text{ is infinite }$$ so that: $$\omega\in\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}B_k\right)^{\complement}\iff\{n\mid \omega\in B_n\}\text{ is finite }$$or equivalently:$$\omega\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}B_k^{\complement}\iff\{n\mid \omega\in B_n\}\text{ is finite }$$As quasi comments: we are not dealing with probabilities here but with events.

We can state that:$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}B_k^{\complement}\right)=P(\text{event }B_n\text{ will occur for only a finite number of indices})$$

Comment: @altruism Note that the final event says (in words): there is some $n$ (union) such that for all (intersection) $k \ge n$ you're not in $B_k$ (so $B_k$ fails). Which happens exactly when there only finitely many $B_k$ occurring. Look up lim sup and lim inf of sequences of sets..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you so much! Great explanation.